# How to check multiple checkboxes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, input

I've just started to learn JavaScript and have run into a issue trying to get multiple checkboxes to work.

I am trying to calculate the cost of a product based on the options checked. However, my script is automatically assuming that all the boxes have been checked.

What is wrong with this code? Sorry if its a basic question but I have been banging my head for hours now.

```
function cal() {

    var selectionOne = 0;
    var selectionTwo = 0;
    var selectionThree = 0;
    var total = 0;


    if (document.getElementById("1").checked = true ){
        selectionOne = 25;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("2").checked = true ){
        selectionTwo = 50;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("3").checked = true ){
        selectionThree = 100;
    }

    total = selectionOne + selectionTwo + selectionThree;

    alert ("Your total is £" + total);

}
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Basic Pricing Script</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <p>Please select which options you want from the list</p>

    <form name="priceoptions">

      <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="big" value="big"> Big Prints<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="medium" value="medium" > Medium Prints<br>
      <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="small" value="small"  > Small Prints<br>
      <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="cal()">

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In an "if" statement, you need two equal symbols to compare for equality, not just one. `document.getElementById("1").checked == true`.

Comment: No need for the `== true` part. And all of this can be condensed. Check out my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator. For comparisons, you need to use `==` or `===`.

- `==`: This compares by type
- `===` This compares by type and value

Also, saying `.checked == true` is redundant. You can just use `.checked`. Furthermore, there is no reason to declare the variables, and then set their values on seperate lines. You can reduce the code by using the ternary operator.

Check out this snippet.

```js
function cal() {
    var s1 = document.getElementById("1").checked ? 25 : 0;
    var s2 = document.getElementById("2").checked ? 50 : 0;
    var s3 = document.getElementById("3").checked ? 100 : 0;
    var total = s1 + s2 + s3;
    alert ("Your total is £" + total);
}
```

```html
<p>Please select which options you want from the list</p>

<form name="priceoptions">
  <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="big" value="big"> Big Prints<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="medium" value="medium" > Medium Prints<br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="small" value="small"  > Small Prints<br>
  <input type="submit" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="cal()">
</form>
```

Comment: What's the *difference* between using `==` and `===`? :) (I know, but others may not)

Comment: Ok this is very interesting.How would you check if it was not checked? also i can set the variables value between checked and not checked by using : this looks so much nicer

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1):

Your comparisons are not correct. A single "=" is not the correct way to compare values you need "==" for truthy and "===" for an exact match.
Change it to

```
if (document.getElementById("1").checked == true ){
    selectionOne = 25;    
}
```

Comment: Ohh god i was being so silly not remembering this! Sorry for such a noob question! would it be any benifit going with === over == here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare two values in JavaScript you have to use == or === operators:

```
if (document.getElementById("1").checked == true ){
```

also you can simplify this if:

```
if (document.getElementById("1").checked){
```