# How to have two radio buttons of one group checked at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I have a pricing table where I put radio buttons on the top of the table and on the bottom.

No matter if the user clicks on the radio button on the top or bottom, I want both radio buttons to be checked at the same time.

```html
<input type="radio" name="group1">If you check me...<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1">...I also want to be checked
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="group2">If you check me...<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2">...I also want to be checked
<br><br><br> Just a pic of a cat
<br>
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/07/c3/45/07c345d0eca11d0bc97c894751ba1b46.jpg" />
```

https://codepen.io/Insane415/pen/mwOOWM

Comment: You can give them a unique `name` and then use javascript to select both when you click on one. Is that an option? you didn't tag the post with JS.

Comment: That won't work, the point of a radio input is to have a singular value for an option.. e.g. a radio input is appropriate for yes/no parts of a form (basic example). It's done on the inputs name value, so your two `group1` fields can never be simultaneously selected, best bet is to name the top two, group1 and group 2 and the bottom ones group 3 and 4 and use jQuery/JS to select the radios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Radio buttons don't work that way. You can only select one at a time in a group.

You should use checkboxes instead.

> [**4.10.5.1.13 Radio Button state
>   (`type=radio`)**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#radio-button-state-(type=radio))
>
> The `input` element represents a control that, when used in
>   conjunction with other `input` elements, forms a *radio button group*
>   in which only one control can have its checkedness state set to true.

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible with checkboxes to check two with one click?

Comment: Multiple checked checkboxes is normal and valid HTML. You can use a script to make it happen automatically. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41900751/3597276

Comment: Also, if you're going to use scripts, then put the radio buttons in different groups, and have one checked manually result in another checked automatically. As long as they are in different groups, radio buttons can still work.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I have now written a script for it. This was my first time using jquery and I'm sure the code could be a lot easier, but well, it works.

Answer (score 0):

yes use checkboxes instead and increase border-radius to let them look like a radio

Answer (score -4):

```html
<input type="radio" name="group1">If you check me...<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1">...I also want to be checked
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="group2">If you check me...<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2">...I also want to be checked
<br><br><br> Just a pic of a cat
<br>
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/07/c3/45/07c345d0eca11d0bc97c894751ba1b46.jpg" />
```